# Find maximum value out of values

Tags: pine-script

I need to find the maximum value of the above variables in Pine SCript Version 4 but I am not able to do so since it is giving a compiling error

```
Code Logic 
myVolume1 = (close[1]-close[2])/close[2] > 0 ? 0 : volume[1]
myVolume2 = (close[2]-close[3])/close[3] > 0 ? 0 : volume[2]
myVolume3 = (close[3]-close[4])/close[4] > 0 ? 0 : volume[3]
myVolume4 = (close[4]-close[5])/close[5] > 0 ? 0 : volume[4]
myVolume5 = (close[5]-close[6])/close[6] > 0 ? 0 : volume[5]
myVolume6 = (close[6]-close[7])/close[7] > 0 ? 0 : volume[6]
myVolume7 = (close[7]-close[8])/close[8] > 0 ? 0 : volume[7]
myVolume8 = (close[8]-close[9])/close[9] > 0 ? 0 : volume[8]
myVolume9 = (close[9]-close[10])/close[10] > 0 ? 0 : volume[9]
myVolume10 = (close[10]-close[11])/close[11] > 0 ? 0 : volume[10]

test = volume > max(myVolume1,myVolume2,myVolume3,myVolume4,myVolume5,myVolume6,myVolume7,myVolume8,myVolume9,myVolume10)
```

I am storing 10 values based on a condition and I need to find the max of that vvalue and compare it with volume to assign the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this

```
//@version=4
study("test", overlay=true)

arr = array.new_float()

for i = 1 to 10
    array.push(arr, (close[i]-close[i+1])/close[i+1] > 0 ? 0 : volume[i])

test = volume > array.max(arr)

plot(na)
```

Edit: Volume coloring as requested in the comments.
Pine doesn't allow the volume bars to be colored, so we'll have to recreate the volume bars.
There are 2 options here:

Option 1: Use a separate panel to draw the volume

```
//@version=4
study("test - separate panel")

arr = array.new_float()

for i = 1 to 10
    array.push(arr, (close[i]-close[i+1])/close[i+1] > 0 ? 0 : volume[i])

condition = volume > array.max(arr) ? 1 : 0
volumeUp = change(volume) > 0
vColor = condition ? color.black : volumeUp ? color.green : color.red

plot(volume, style=plot.style_columns, color=vColor)
```

Option 2: Overlayed on the main chart, but then you need to plot the volume on the left scale.

```
//@version=4
study("test - scale left", overlay=true, scale=scale.left)

arr = array.new_float()

for i = 1 to 10
    array.push(arr, (close[i]-close[i+1])/close[i+1] > 0 ? 0 : volume[i])

condition = volume > array.max(arr) ? 1 : 0
volumeUp = change(volume) > 0
vColor = condition ? color.black : volumeUp ? color.green : color.red

plot(volume, style=plot.style_columns, color=vColor)
```

Comment: Hi Bjorn..It worked thanks ..Any idea I have a condition where if it is true colour teh volume as black colour otherwise nothing....

Comment: I've modified my answer to include colored volume bars as per your request. If you feel that it solved your problem, please mark the answer as accepted so that others can benefit from it too. Thank you.

Comment: I want to have on the chart instead of the seperate panel but its hiding teh chart....Not able to attach the screenshot

Comment: Use code from option 2. See study() tag. It contains scale=scale.left